# Can't use C++11 features when building with Qt

Tags: macos, qt, c++11, qt5

I'm on OS X 10.8.4 (Mountain Lion) with the latest command line tools from Xcode. I'm trying to build a Qt project (in Qt Creator) which uses some C++11 features; notably `std::unique_ptr`. Whenever I try building though, I get the following error:

> clang: error: invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++ (requires OS X 10.7 or later)

My .pro file is as follows:

```
QT       += core gui

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
LIBS += -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -stdlib=libc++

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = APPNAME
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
cache()
```

I've tried the solutions presented in other answers (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749315/clang-under-qtcreator-cant-work-with-c11) and the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081490/qt-5-0-and-c11-with-osx-mountain-lion)), neither of which seemed to work.

Comment: Please try adding `CONFIG += c++11`. I don't have access to osx so I cannot test it.

Comment: Your error is `requires OS X 10.7 or later` - what is you OS X version? Is it OS X 10.7 or later, as **required** by the project?

Comment: @Ali Ha! Wow... Can't believe it was that easy! Could you respond to this as an actual answer so I can give you proper credit?

Comment: @Lander I am glad it helped. Posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [this site](http://woboq.com/blog/cpp11-in-qt5.html) add

`CONFIG += c++11`

to your .pro file (see at the bottom of that web page). It requires Qt 5.

---

**UPDATE:** As for Qt 4, see [How to enable C++11 in Qt Creator?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16950073/341970)

Comment: Thanks for making this an answer, and for the response. Don't know how I missed this.

Comment: Are there any solutions for Qt4?